# CSS: Error in Toggle Classes By using Class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to toggle classes by using class name.
My code is working fine when i am toggling `using id`.
how can i make it work only one red should be visible at one time.

```js
function hideshowmenu() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  element.classList.toggle("bg-red");
}
```

```css
.bg-red {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainmenu " onclick="hideshowmenu()">RED1</div>
<div id="submenu" class="submenu">
  <div class="mainmenu " onclick="hideshowmenu()">RED2</div>
  <div id="box" class="box"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As an FYI: this is not the best way to create toggles nor lists. The element to click for the toggle should be focusable, which a div is not (by default). Something like a button or `a` are better options. Lists are better suited for `ul` or `ol` elements.

Comment: Spot the difference `getElementsByClassName` vs `getElementById`

Answer (score 4):

As the name of [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) suggest, it returns element**S**, so you are getting HTMLCollection, not one element. Query the first one, like this:

```js
function hideshowmenu() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];
  element.classList.toggle("bg-red");
}
```

or:

```js
function hideshowmenu() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  elements[0].classList.toggle("bg-red");
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69750703/js-how-to-make-sure-only-child-div-is-toggled-on-click

Answer (score 3):

What is returned by document.getElementsByClassName("box"); is a collection. You need to specify the index to access the classList property.

You are doing:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
element.classList.toggle("bg-red");
```

When you should be doing

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
element[0].classList.toggle("bg-red");
```

You could also loop through the elements if you want to toggle multiple values.

Example code fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/agy5jtb0/1/

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName("box")` return a collection of elements, but you considered it as a single element that is your mistake.
I suggest something like this:

`html`:

```
<div class="mainmenu " onclick="hideshowmenu(this)">RED1</div>
<div id="submenu" class="submenu">
    <div class="mainmenu" onclick="hideshowmenu(this)">RED2</div>
    <div id="box" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

`js`:

```
function hideshowmenu(el) {
    el.classList.toggle("bg-red");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this (not sure If is this what you need):

```js
function hideshowmenu() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  for (let a of elements) {
    a.classList.toggle("bg-red");
  }
}
```

```css
.bg-red{
  margin-top:10px;
  background-color:red;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainmenu " onclick="hideshowmenu(this)">RED1</div>
<div id="submenu" class="submenu">
    <div class="mainmenu" onclick="hideshowmenu(this)">RED2</div>
    <div id="box" class="box"></div>
</div>
```