# JS: How to make sure only child div is toggled on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given example is working fine but red color is showing under Box2 only.

How to make sure if box1 is clicked then red should show below Box1,
if Box2 is clicked box should show below box 2.

**[CODEPEN](https://jsfiddle.net/kyt9pofj/)**

```js
function hideshowmenu() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  element[0].classList.toggle("bg-red");
}
```

```css
.bg-red {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainmenu " onclick="hideshowmenu()">BOX1</div>
<div id="box" class="box"></div>


<div class="mainmenu " onclick="hideshowmenu()">BOX2</div>
<div id="box" class="box"></div>
```

only one red should show at one time.

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to just show a red bit below the relevant box or is it more than that - are you actually wanting to show a submenu related to the particular box?

Comment: yes i want to show submenu, only one red should show, and without loop is it possible?

Comment: `element[0].classList.toggle("bg-red");` With [0] you are always selecting the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `box`-id is duplicated, not allowed in HTML. Next, using [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) makes your life easier. If you want the class of `div.box` after a clicked `div.mainmenu` element to be `bg-red`, the next snippet may be an idea (note: creates 100 `div.mainmenu` elements *after* the handler is assigned).

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);
createSomeBoxes();

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains(`mainmenu`)) {
//^ act only on div.mainmenu  
    const currentBox = document.querySelector(`.bg-red`);
    currentBox && currentBox.classList.remove(`bg-red`);
    
    return currentBox && currentBox.previousElementSibling === evt.target 
      ? true : evt.target.nextElementSibling.classList.add(`bg-red`);
  }
}

// for demo
function createSomeBoxes() {
  let nBoxes = 0;
  while(nBoxes++ < 100) {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`,
    `<div class="mainmenu">BOX ${nBoxes}</div>
     <div class="box"></div>`);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
  font: 12px/15px verdana, arial;
}

.mainmenu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bg-red {
  margin-top: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20vw;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, if i click on box1 it shows red under it, if i click again on box1 it's not hiding red?

Comment: Yep. But ok, edited, now it does.

Comment: i was wondering is it possible to show 10 lines of red (box) under box1 onclick?

Comment: Ofcourse. Just wrap the 10 boxes in a separate element. See [this stackblitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lk1f3c?file=index.js)

Comment: in js code i am replacing .bg-red with display:hidden/block, it'll have same code for hidden block?

Comment: I suppose it does. You just have to try it out (fork my - or create your own [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) snippet)

Answer (score 1):

First remove the id's, you dont need them (and theyre not unique so they arent valid anyways).

Then youll need to iterate trough all your `.mainmenu` items and bin a click to hide all boxes and open the one right besides the item you clicked.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".mainmenu").forEach(function(menuElement) {
  menuElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".box").forEach(function(boxElement) {
      boxElement.classList.remove("bg-red");
    });

    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("bg-red");
  });
});
```

```css
.bg-red {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainmenu">BOX1</div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="mainmenu">BOX2</div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="mainmenu">BOX3</div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="mainmenu">BOX4</div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="mainmenu">BOX5</div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="mainmenu">BOX6</div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="mainmenu">BOX7</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: i have 100 of ids same situation i will have to write 100 ids?

Comment: only one red should show at one time.

Comment: No, you could also rewrite it to be more generic.

Comment: @Fayakon i updated my answer including "only one red at a time" and beign generic so you dont need to repeat IDs (removed Ids completely).

Comment: Thankyou , is it possible to do without loop?

Comment: @Fayakon most likely not, since you wanna do it for a unknown number of elements. You could use jquery instead which will do a loop internally still.

Comment: i was wondering is it possible to show 10 lines of red (box) under box1 onclick?

Answer (score 1):

You only trigger  [0]

I would delegate

I also removed ID since IDs need to be unique

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const boxes = container.querySelectorAll(".box")
container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("mainmenu")) {
    const thisBox = tgt.nextElementSibling;
    boxes.forEach(box => {
      if (box != thisBox) box.classList.remove("bg-red");
    })
    thisBox.classList.toggle("bg-red");
  }
})
```

```css
.bg-red {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="mainmenu">BOX1</div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="mainmenu">BOX2</div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: only one red should show at any given time.

Comment: Thankyou so much, means alot, is there anyway to do without loop? or loop is must in such condition?

Comment: Unless you want to use jQuery or some  complicated CSS, a loop is needed

Comment: And jQuery loops under the hood anyway

Comment: i was wondering is it possible to show 10 lines of red (box) under box1 onclick?

Comment: Yes. Everything is possible. You can wrap 10 boxes in a div, then just toggle that

Comment: see: https://jsfiddle.net/y10sv5p6/

Comment: What is the usecase? Can you explain whast you want to do and why? PS: You have too many </divs> in your fidddle

Comment: i have responsive dropdown menu i want to show submenus on click.

Answer (score 1):

You should use event object to get a target node, and then append div with the class after it. The `after` function will move the div each time.

```html
<div  class="mainmenu" onClick="hideshowmenu(event)">BOX1</div>          
<div  class="mainmenu"  onClick="hideshowmenu(event)">BOX2</div>
```

```js
const redBox = document.createElement('div');
redBox.classList.add('bg-red');

function hideshowmenu(event) {
  const elem = event.target;
  elem.after(redBox)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hj0rgkfp/

Comment: either box1 or box2 only one red should be visible.

Comment: Another way is to create a node in javascript and just move it after the target div



https://jsfiddle.net/hj0rgkfp/

Comment: i don't want to create div using JS